# libpdcurses.a setting for Pdcurses

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference, pdcurses

I'm working on a program in which I use **PDCurses3.5** functions using **i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe**.
When I compile the program, I keep getting errors such as `"undefined reference to 'COLS'"`, `"undefined reference to 'lines'"`.
I have checked that `<curses.h>` header and the library package properly installed.
Here is my input line:

```
> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe set.o read.o elements.o random.o
> -L../standard/test -lplotfit -lplotget -lgfortran -Wl,--subsystem,console -mwindows -o runtime/mingw/result -lm -static -lws2_32  -lpdcurses
```

And the first part of the error is:

```
../standard/bin/mingw/menu.o:menu.c:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `COLS' 
../standard/bin/mingw/menu.o:menu.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `COLS' 
../standard/bin/mingw/menu.o:menu.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `LINES' 
../standard/bin/mingw/menu.o:menu.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `MOVE' 
../standard/bin/mingw/menu.o:menu.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `initscr'
...
```

It seems the program cannot refer to libpdcurses.a in its library file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: did you check path of libpdcurses.a you may try to copy libpdcurses.a to your current directory where gcc linker runs and try again. In Msys2 i successfully compile and run pdcurses libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-lpdcurses`, the linker looks for `libpdcurses.a` in certain predefined locations, plus those specified via `-L`. But, by default, the library is built as `pdcurses.a`. To link it, you can directly specify its location; e.g.:

```
gcc -oprogname.exe progname.c pdcurses.a
```

or

```
gcc -oprog2.exe prog2.c /pdcurses/win32/pdcurses.a
```

Alternatively, you can rename the library to `libpdcurses.a`, and either copy it to a location in the existing search path, or use `-L`:

```
gcc -oprogname.exe progname.c -lpdcurses
```

or

```
gcc -oprog2.exe prog2.c -L/pdcurses/win32 -lpdcurses
```